# Opening Master page from MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an issue with accessing **Master** page from **CarouselPage**. **Master** page is accessible from all other pages by swipe (as expected) but not from my **CarouselPage**, I'm navigating to it like:

```
MasterDetailPageVariable.Detail = new CarouselPage{
 //code adding new pages
};
```

I mentioned the problem with this on an official documentation [page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselPage/).

I tried adding:

> Note: When embedding a CarouselPage into a MasterDetailPage.Detail,
> application developers should set MasterDetailPage.IsGestureEnabled to
> false to prevent gesture conflicts between the CarouselPage and
> MasterDetailPage.

But unfortunately this didn't do the trick for me. Could you please help me to resolve this issue - I really stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the resolution of my problem, to display **Master** page you can use next "trick":

```
MasterDetailPageVariable.isPresented = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve this by using `MessagingCenter`. Please have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed) especially at this [line](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/blob/master/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/Views/MainView.cs#L23).
Here is how to use it with [CarouselPage](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/blob/master/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed/Views/HomeView.cs).

Comment: This method changes Detail page, not the Master. I've tried changing it to achieve my needs but Master page still doesn't showing.